# Only allow specific workers to work on my HIT

Tags: python, boto, mechanicalturk

Is there a way that I can do the following in Mechanical  Turk to only allow certain users to work on my project? Something like:

```
from boto.mturk.qualification Qualifications
quals=Qualifications()
quals.add(worker_id__in=['A1NYH6FD37TIU0', 'Z1NYH6FD37TIU0']
```

How would I do this?

Comment: I don't know the python code for this, but basically you need to create a new QualificationType, grant that QualificationType to various workers, and then add a QualificationRequirement to a HIT that you create, restricting it to workers with that Qualification.